# this.state in constructor call function synchronously

Tags: reactjs, redux

So I have the following...

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.props.getCurrentProfile();
         this.state = {
              city:
                this.props.profile.location.city !== ""
                  ? this.props.profile.location.city
                  : "",
              country: "",
              zipcode: "",
    ...
```

These properties are dependent on `this.props.getCurrentProfile()`. Is there a way I can execute `this.state` after `getCurrentProfile` since this is going asynchronously? Also I am aware that conditional rendering for

```
this.props.profile.location.city !== ""
          ? this.props.profile.location.city
          : "",
```

probably won't work I just wanted to see if it did. I know other stuff to do instead, just wanted to try it. But I need my profile to load in to test it first. Because this is coming back as undefined since it's setting the state before Redux loads in the new state.

Comment: It is usually bad practice to unconditionally initialise the state from the props, can't you directly use the prop? If you still want to do it you can use [`getDerivedStateFromProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) which is invoked before every render.

Comment: I absolutely can =p. I was just trying to be an idiot and see if it would work... lol. WHOEVER READS THIS DONT BE LIKE ME!

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps that was suggested in answers is deprecated. getDerivedStateFromProps has to be used instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.props.getCurrentProfile();

  this.state = {
          city: "",
          country: "",
          zipcode: "",
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    if(nextProps.profile) {
      this.setState({ city: nextProps.profile.location.city })
    }
  }
```

Once the action `getCurrentProfile` invoked, and value returned, `componentWillReceiveProps` will be receiving the new props `profile`, hence setState in `componentWillReceiveProps`

Comment: I was going to do this if I couldn't think of a way to do it synchronously.  I am just trying to be too difficult XD. Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 3):

Since `componentWillReceiveProps` is deprecated I would recommend you to use `static getDerivedStateFromProps`.

I would recommend you to compare two objects before doing setState in getDerivedStateFromProps. If both the objects are not equal then do setState otherwise you will get into infinite setState loop warning. You should always compare current props with previous props and if they are not equal only then do setState. So to compare two objects I would recommend you to use underscore module for deep equality check. Please check my updated answer below

```
constructor(props) {
  super(props);
  this.props.getCurrentProfile();

  this.state = {
          city: "",
          country: "",
          zipcode: "",
  }

  static getDerivedStateFromProps(nextProps, prevState) {
    if(!_.isEqual(this.props.profile, nextProps.profile)) {
      return ({ city: nextProps.profile.location.city }) // <- this is setState equivalent
    }
    return null;
  }
```

Comment: Your name suites this question. Thanks! =]

Comment: Ha ha. You are welcome. I am trying to act according to my name:)

Comment: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated.

Comment: @estus Thank you for correcting me. I updated my answer. Hope it make sense now